# Move file around in s3 in the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to move a file/folder somewhere in the same bucket but in another place in the hierarchy using only the browser.

I know there is s3fuse or command line tools but I want to do it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the AWS Console, you can right click on the original file, select Cut and then go to the new location and select Paste. This will move the file from the old location to the new one.

Comment: Apparently, I need another pair of eyes. Thanks!